# I can't access "this.props.match.params.id" in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, frontend, react-router-dom

My parent component's code where I am setting up my props is this :-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Anime = (props) => (
  <tr>
    <td> {props.anime.animeName}</td>
    <td>
      <Link to={"/anime/edit/" + props.anime._id}>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
      </Link>
    </td>
   </tr>
); 

animeList() {
    return this.state.animes.map((animeObject) => {
      return (
        <Anime
          anime={animeObject}
          key={animeObject._id}
        />
      );
    });
  }
```

My parent component is working perfectly.

```
http://localhost:3000/anime/edit/5eb2f493091abc64b44bad23
```

BUT when I try to access the ID passed to my url, I am getting "undefined".

Child Component's Code, where I am getting the error

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const anime = {
      animeName: this.state.animeName,
    };

    console.log("The ID is ", this.props.match.params.id) // getting UNDEFINED

    axios
      .put("http://localhost:4000/animes/update/" + this.props.match.params.id, anime)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

I want to access The ID in my url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPDATE` The best option is probably to use useLocation hook.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router'

const MyChildComponent = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation()

  // You can location object
  return <div />
}

export default MyChildComponent
```

---

You can wrap Your child component in `withRouter`. Someting like that

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

const MyChildComponent = (props) => {
  // You can use props here
  return <div />
}

export default withRouter(MyChildComponent)
```

The code snippet You provided doesn't seem to be complete, but props can only be accessed from inside of a react component.

Alternatively, You can use a different way to extract the id from url. Something that doesn't include react-router. For example

```
const path = window.location.pathname.split('/')
const id = path[path.length - 1]
```